jsPDF autotable | How to make different styles in one field?
I tried to complete the text separately, but I don’t like this option. I still need to change the font in this column
const rows: (string | string)[][] = [];  data.items.forEach((item) => { rows.push([ ${item.nameOfItem}\n${item.descriptOfItem}, ${item.quantity}, ${item.unitPrice}.00$, ${item.tax}%,  ${(item.quantity * item.unitPrice).toFixed(2)}$]); });
How it looks now
{item.descriptOfItem} should be in a smaller font and located under item.nameOfItem
